# Can string formatting be used in text shown with DebuggerDisplay?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging

I want to apply the `DebuggerDisplayAttribute` to include an memory address value.
Is there a way to have it displayed in hexadecimal?

```
[DebuggerDisplay("Foo: Address value is {Address}")] 
class Foo 
{
    System.IntPtr m_Address = new System.IntPtr(43981); // Sample value


    System.IntPtr Address
    {
         get { return m_Address; }
    }
}
```

This will display:  `Foo: Address value is 43981`
Instead, I'd like the value to be displayed in hex, like that: `Foo: Address value is 0xABCD`.

I know that I could apply all kinds of formatting by overriding `ToString()`, but I'm curious if the same is possible with DebuggerDisplayAttributes.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes you can use any method off the properties just as you would normally.
`[DebuggerDisplay("Foo: Address value is {Address.ToString(\"<formatting>\"}")]`   is an example

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x810d419.aspx

Comment: While this is possible, I recommend against it. It takes away the choice to display numbers as hexadecimal or decimal. If you do not append text to it, it's also printed with quotes at the start and end, so it will eventually cause `"0xDEADBEEF"` to appear in the debugger windows, which at first looks like a string rather an integer.

Answer (score 21):

There's a tip recommended by https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaredpar/2011/03/18/debuggerdisplay-attribute-best-practices/

Basically, create a private **property**, say, `DebugDisplay`. Have the property return a formatted string of your choice. Then just make use of your new private property in the `DebuggerDisplay` attribute.

For e.g.

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{DebugDisplay,nq}")]
public sealed class Student {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    private string DebugDisplay {
        get { return string.Format("Student: {0} {1}", FirstName, LastName); }
    }
}
```

I find this way to be much more readable.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to view values in hex format, there is an option in Visual Studio to display values in that format.  While debugging, hover over your variable to bring up the debugging display, or find a variable in your watch or locals window.  Right-click on the variable and select the "Hexadecimal Display" option.  The debugger will then display all numeric values in hexadecimal format.
In this case, you will get:  "Foo: Address value is 0x0000abcd"

Unfortunately I couldn't see any way to really control the format of the string that is displayed by the DebuggerDisplay attribute as you were asking.

Answer (score 2):

From Microsoft's own documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/format-specifiers-in-csharp?view=vs-2017

You can display a value in hexadecimal format by adding `,h` to the evaluation of the expression.

This also works very well with the `DebuggerDisplay` attribute.

[image]